# In python, how to generate a random integer in a range, excluding some numbers in a list?

Tags: python, random

For example, at beginning I want generate a random integer from (0,9),

at first time, the program generate 2, then I put 2 in the 'excluding' list,

next time, I need generate a number ranging between 0 to 9, and excluding 2. let's say it the second turn, the program generate 5.

The third turn, I need generate a number ranging from 0 to 9 and excluding 2 and 5.

As the range is very huge (million level), is there any method is efficient?

Comment: How is 0-9 "million level"?

Comment: Just create a list of numbers between 0 and 9 and then shuffle it, then iterate through it.

Comment: Why do you need a million? Sounds like a requirement that should be laterally traversed to me...

Comment: @jonrsharpe 0-9 is am example. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generate the possible values **once**, shuffle that and pop values from that list each time:

```
values = range(10)
random.shuffle(values)

def get_value():
    return values.pop()
```

This will eventually produce all values in the range, in random order, without repetition.

Answer (score 4):

As per [the documentation for `random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample):

> To choose a sample from a range of integers, use an `xrange()` object as
>   an argument. This is especially fast and space efficient for sampling
>   from a large population: `sample(xrange(10000000), 60)`.

This will sample without replacement, so `random.sample(xrange(n), k)` gives `k` *different* numbers in the range `[0, n)` (for `k <= n`).

Answer (score 0):

You could use function which maps integer range into same integer range with exceptions, like this:

```
import random

def excection(val, exceptions):
    ''' Maps range of values into
        similar range of values with exceptions missing.
        Exceptions must be sorted increasingly.

        for excample with exceptions=(2, 5) it will map
        This:       0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
        To this:    0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8
    '''
    if not exceptions:
        return val

    for e in exceptions:
        if val < e: 
            return val # value before any exclusion is unchanged
        val += 1 # after some exclusion value is larger by one

    return val


def randint_with_exceptions(min, max, exceptions):
    r = random.randint(min, max - len(exceptions)) # generate random number in range smaller then desired by number of exceptions
    return excection(r, exceptions) # and map it to desired, more sparse sequence

for i in range(20): # test possible randoms
    print randint_with_exceptions(0, 7, (2, 5)),

from functools import partial
ex_25 = partial(excection, exceptions=(2, 5))
assert ( # unittest sequence transformation
    map(ex_25, range(5))
    == [0, 1, 3, 4, 6]
)
```